# SKShapeNode Positioning

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skshapenode

I'm poking around SpriteKit and encountered some weirdness
i.e i'm simply adding  rectangular `SKShapeNode`that should be fullscreen on iPhone

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let _box            = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: self.frame.size)
    _box.strokeColor    = SKColor.blueColor()
    _box.fillColor      = SKColor.blueColor()
    _box.position       = CGPointMake(200, 200)
    _box.name           = "box"
    self.addChild(_box)

    let _player         = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
    _player.position    = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    _player.fillColor   = SKColor.redColor()
    _player.strokeColor = SKColor.redColor()
    _player.name        = "player"
    _player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50)
    _player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    _player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    self.addChild(_player)

    let _ground         = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.width, 20))
    _ground.name        = "ground"
    _ground.position    = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    _ground.fillColor   = SKColor.greenColor()
    _ground.strokeColor = SKColor.greenColor()
    _ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.width, 20))
    _ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.addChild(_ground)
}
```

My views are initialised this way
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

}
```

The resulting scene looks like so: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otwFS.png)

All Nodes are shifted to the left-bottom.
Basically left-bottom corner of rectangular shapes is out of bounds (i've checked that by positioning blue shape to (200, 200) instead of (0, 0) - and left-bottome edges were still out of screen frame.

Anchor point for scene is set to (0, 0) so the basically it looks like for me, that it sets position for central point of shape.

What is a best way to define position of left-bottom corner of the Node, instead of mid-point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a shape using a bezier path or CGPath, you can specify the position of its "anchor point," where the path's origin specifies the bottom/left corner of the path. For example,

```
    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    SKShapeNode *shape = [SKShapeNode node];
    shape.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
    shape.fillColor = [SKColor blueColor];
```

Also, if your deployment target is iOS 8, you can create your shape node with

```
    SKShapeNode *shape = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    shape.fillColor = [SKColor blueColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
_box.position       = CGPointMake(self.size.width*.5, self.size.height*.5)
```

This will position the center of your sprite at the center of the screen.

Comment: yes, that's obvious, thanks. but is there an way to define left-bottom corner position of node, not a mid-point one?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the anchorPoint method as well.

Comment: As far as i understood – `anchorPoint` basically affects a position of texture on the node, not a node's position itself.

and as for `SKShapeNode` - it doesn't have `anchorPoint` property at all

Comment: Sorry,  SKSpriteNode does have that property which you could make a square out of but I see that you need other properties of SKShapeNode.  The method in my answer is the easiest by far. You could just use some simple math to position it, accounting for where the bottom left will actually be placed.